# Modifying the parent datarow in a Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, datagrid

I have a datagrid in SL5, and the item source is a list of a custom class. All of the columns except one are regular DataGridTextColumns with nothing fancier other than binding to a property of the class that is the data source. One of the columns, however, is a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a CheckBox. When the checkbox is checked/unchecked, I am trying to modify the particular underlying element in the item source. How do I access the particular element that the checkbox in question is part of?

I have my grid defined like so:

```
      <data:DataGrid x:Name="ExceptionGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Policy" Binding="{Binding PolicyName}" />
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Retention" Binding="{Binding Retention,Converter={StaticResource BackupRetentionConverter}}" />
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Approved?">
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding .,Converter={StaticResource ApprovalConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Exception" Binding="{Binding ExceptionMessage}" />

        </data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

To make the checkbox checked/unchecked on initial binding, I made a converter that does this:

```
  public class ApprovalConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var detail = (BackupExceptionDetail) value;
        if (detail.IsApproved) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when my Checked event fires, the sender is the CheckBox itself and I don't know how get to the actual data item that the checkbox is bound to:

```
      private void ToggleButton_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var detail = (BackupExceptionDetail)sender; // <--- dies here, as the sender is a checkbox
        detail.IsApproved = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `checkBox.DataContext` to get the object it is bound to.

Comment: Bam! Works! As soon as stackoverflow lets me accept your answer, this is it. Thanks!